# Introducing Nan's when concatenating list of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, nan

I am looping through a data frame, doing some calculations, and then depending on some logic adding the original series or a transformed version. For a MRE, I'll leave out the transformation part.

```
    # List of Tuples
students = [('Ankit', 22, 'A'),
           ('Swapnil', 22, 'B'),
           ('Priya', 22, 'B'),
           ('Shivangi', 22, 'B'),
            ]

# Create a DataFrame object
stu_df = pd.DataFrame(students, columns =['Name', 'Age', 'Section'],
                      index =['1', '2', '3', '4'])

returnList = []

for i, (colname, series) in enumerate(stu_df.iteritems()):
    returnList.append(pd.DataFrame(series))

a = pd.concat(returnList)
```

the index is consistent across the series, so why is is not being recognized cleanly?
a looks like this, but it should line up to look like the original data?:

| index | Name | Age | Section |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ankit |  | NaN |
| 2 | Swapnil | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | Priya | NaN | NaN |
| 4 | Shivangi | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | NaN | 22.0 | NaN |
| 2 | NaN | 22.0 | NaN |
| 3 | NaN | 22.0 | NaN |
| 4 | NaN | 22.0 | NaN |
| 1 | NaN | NaN | A |
| 2 | NaN | NaN | B |
| 3 | NaN | NaN | B |
| 4 | NaN | NaN | B |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `axis=1` to `pd.concat()`:

```
a = pd.concat(returnList, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> a
       Name  Age Section
1     Ankit   22       A
2   Swapnil   22       B
3     Priya   22       B
4  Shivangi   22       B
```

#### Explanation

By default, `pd.concat` tries to concatenate the dataframes vertically (`axis=0`), i.e., adding the second df to the end of the first, and the third to the end of that. But since all the Series object in `returnList` have *different column names*, pandas adds them to the end, and fills in the missing spaces with NaN:

```
>>> pd.concat(returnList)
       Name   Age Section
1     Ankit   NaN     NaN  <--- first df of returnList starts here
2   Swapnil   NaN     NaN
3     Priya   NaN     NaN
4  Shivangi   NaN     NaN
1       NaN  22.0     NaN  <--- second df of returnList starts here
2       NaN  22.0     NaN
3       NaN  22.0     NaN
4       NaN  22.0     NaN
1       NaN   NaN       A  <--- third df of returnList starts here
2       NaN   NaN       B
3       NaN   NaN       B
4       NaN   NaN       B
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) concatenates along the index. You want to concatenate horizontally, so must set `axis=1`.

```
a = pd.concat(returnList, axis=1)
```